# Should we include all tables of database in E-R diagram?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have admin table which is not linked with any other by a foreign key. So should i include it in ER diagram or not. If yes how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E-R Diagram is just a tool to aid in development of the database or for merely understanding it. Showing that table in the diagram completely depends on you as it is still an entity in the data store that does some sort of job (I presume).

If you do want to include it, you just put the table sitting there with no relationships to any other entity in the diagram.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much... Your answer helped to clear my doubt.

Comment: No Problem... are all your doubts cleared? If yes then accept some answer as the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Okay... I have done it. I didn't know as i am new here.

Comment: No problem! Now you do :)

Answer (score 1):

ER diagram should include all your database tables. Not all tables need to be connected to each other.